# Is there an easier way of deserialising arrays with different elements using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I get data from an API in this form:

```
[
  1234,
  {
    "a": [
      [
        "5541.30000",
        "2.50700000",
        "1534614248.456738",
        "r"
      ],
      [
        "5542.50000",
        "0.40100000",
        "1534614248.456738",
        "r"
      ]
    ],
    "c": "974942666"
  },
  "book-25",
  "XBT/USD"
]
```

The order of the fields in this array data dictates what field in my C# class it maps to. The elements have different types so can't be mapped to a single List or array as far as I know. I want deserialise this into the following class structure:

```cs
    public class MessageResponseBookSnapshot: MessageResponseBase
    {
        public int ChannelID { get; set; }
        public BookSnapshot Book { get; set; }
        public string ChannelName { get; set; }
        public string Pair { get; set; }
    }

    public class BookSnapshot
    {
        public OrderbookLevel[] As { get; set; }
        public OrderbookLevel[] Bs { get; set; }
    }


    public class OrderbookLevel
    {
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public decimal Volume { get; set; }
        public decimal Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Note there are some difference between the JSON and the C# classes, this is information that is not relevant to me so I discard it. If it makes deserialisation easier to include these in the class I am happy to do that. I cannot change the format in which I receive the data.

The problem is I don't know how to get the JSON serialiser to automatically recognise the mappings, eg. that the first element of the array maps to `ChannelID`. Instead I've implemented the serialisation myself like this:

```cs
private static MessageResponseBase DeserialiseBookUpdate(string message)
        {
            using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(message))
            {
                var deserialisedMessage = new MessageResponseBookSnapshot();
                JsonElement root = document.RootElement;
                var arrayEnumerator = root.EnumerateArray();
                arrayEnumerator.MoveNext();
                deserialisedMessage.ChannelID = arrayEnumerator.Current.GetInt32();

                var bookSnapshot = new BookSnapshot();
...cut for brevity...
                deserialisedMessage.Book = bookSnapshot;
                return deserialisedMessage;
            }
        }
```

This is very cumbersome, ideally I would be looking for some kind of attribute that can be applied to the fields of the class. Is there a better way to this so that the JSON serialiser can find the mappings to my data structures, instead of having to manually map them myself?

EDIT:

I wanted to highlight as well that some of the fields don't map to their type, so for example, the JSON contains decimal numbers inside quotes, which in JSON would be of type `string` but I call `decimal.Parse()` on these after using `GetString()`. For this question, it's not necessary for them to be mapped to decimals, strings would be fine.

Comment: This is a bit of an unconventional way of structuring your JSON, so I don't believe you'll find a built-in way of handling it simply with some attributes or similar. I think your options are either what you've already done or if you need to do this with many different models, you could implement some more generalized deserialization with custom attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a more generic approach, you could create a custom `JsonConverter` that uses custom attributes to identify which types should be converted from a JSON array and which order the properties should be converted in.

First, let's define the attributes we'll use:

```
// Identifies types that should be converted from a JSON array
public class FromJsonArrayAttribute : Attribute { }

// Used to choose which order the properties should be converted in
public class PropertyIndexAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public PropertyIndexAttribute(int index)
    {
        Index = index;
    }
}
```

The `JsonConverter` would look something like the following. Note, that this is a rough version that is just made to handle the example in the question, but should be applicable in most places. You might however want to adjust a bit if for example you need to be able to convert more than just public properties or if null can appear in certain places. Also, the implementation currently can only deserialize and not serialize as you can see:

```
public class ArrayToObjectConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    public ArrayToObjectConverter(JsonSerializerOptions options)
    { }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        // The type we're converting to has a [FromJsonArray] attribute
        return Attribute.IsDefined(typeToConvert, typeof(FromJsonArrayAttribute));
    }

    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            throw new JsonException($"Expected the start of a JSON array but found TokenType {reader.TokenType}");
        }
    
        var propMap = typeToConvert.GetProperties() // Only public properties
            .Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(PropertyIndexAttribute)))
            .ToDictionary(
                prop => prop.GetCustomAttribute<PropertyIndexAttribute>().Index,
                prop => prop);
        var result = Activator.CreateInstance(typeToConvert);
        
        var index = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
            {
                return (T)result;
            }
            else if (propMap.TryGetValue(index, out var prop))
            {
                var value = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(
                    ref reader,
                    prop.PropertyType,
                    options);
                prop.SetValue(result, value);
            }
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
            {
                // Skip this whole object, as the target type
                // has no matching property for this object
                reader.Skip();
            }
            
            index++;
        }
        
        return (T)result;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Because the converter should be able to handle more than one type (it uses a generic type parameter), we need to use a `JsonConverterFactory`

```
public class ArrayToObjectConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return Attribute.IsDefined(typeToConvert, typeof(FromJsonArrayAttribute));
    }

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonConverter converter = (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(ArrayToObjectConverter<>).MakeGenericType(
                new Type[] { type }),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
            binder: null,
            args: new object[] { options },
            culture: null);

        return converter;
    }
}
```

Now we need to annotate our types:

```
[FromJsonArray]
public class MessageResponseBookSnapshot
{
    [PropertyIndex(0)]
    public int ChannelID { get; set; }
    [PropertyIndex(1)]
    public BookSnapshot Book { get; set; }
    [PropertyIndex(2)]
    public string ChannelName { get; set; }
    [PropertyIndex(3)]
    public string Pair { get; set; }
}

public class BookSnapshot
{
    [JsonPropertyName("a")]
    public OrderbookLevel[] As { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("b")]
    public OrderbookLevel[] Bs { get; set; }
}

[FromJsonArray]
public class OrderbookLevel
{
    [PropertyIndex(0)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [PropertyIndex(1)]
    public decimal Volume { get; set; }
    [PropertyIndex(2)]
    public decimal Timestamp { get; set; }
}
```

And as a little bonus, let's handle converting `string`s to `decimal`s:

```
public class DecimalConverter : JsonConverter<decimal>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
    {
        return typeToConvert == typeof(decimal);
    }

    public override decimal Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => reader.TokenType switch
    {
        JsonTokenType.Number => reader.GetDecimal(),
        JsonTokenType.String => decimal.Parse(reader.GetString()),
        _ => throw new JsonException($"Expected a Number or String but got TokenType {reader.TokenType}")
    };

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, decimal value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And lastly, let's do some deserialization:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new ArrayToObjectConverterFactory());
options.Converters.Add(new DecimalConverter());
var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MessageResponseBookSnapshot>(json, options);
```

More information on custom converters can be found [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0).

A working example can be found in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/buRfWI).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I was half way to implementing something similar but yours is already much better. Thank you!